# How to make a dynamic form from db w/o framework?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, forms

I'm on a project using php for the back-end part, and without any framework.

I have a database, my main table, the car table, is linked to other tables (color, weight, max speed, price).

I have a form that allows me to give back to my user his "perfect" car according to all these criteria.

I would like that, when the user selects his car color, let's say blue, in the weight field below, with the options ["car < 2t"; "2t < car < 2.5t"; "car > 2.5t"], if none of the blue cars in my database weighs more than 2.5t, this choice is not displayed.

I'm not sure how to do this without a framework... Does anyone have any clues to give me?

Comment: You should tell us what database you use, what you already tried and give us generally more details. [This guide will tell you how you can improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also I recommend to read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via SQL directly:

```
SELECT
    weight.id,
    weight.value
FROM
    weight
    JOIN color
        ON color.car_id = weight.car_id
        AND color.name = "blue" # <-- Join only blue cars
WHERE
    weight.value > 2500 # <-- only show above 2500
```

Working [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfNtQay7viep6n9urPwuHP/0).

This should help you to get to your desired solution. If you need further help please create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) containing your db-structure and some example content.

Comment: Sorry, I asked my question very badly. I would like my form to be dynamic, that on my first select, onchange, the select below adapt to my choice, without having a refresh of my page...

Comment: Yes, you will need an ajax call, which contains the result of this sql and fill your options accordingly.

Comment: Ok so i'll have to deal with multiples conditions.. Gonna try this, thanks !